# Add column with tuple length (number of items)

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, dataframe

Original DataFrame is just 1 column with tuples. I want to add a column with the number of items in each tuple (length).

```
           ITEMS
0   (EGG, WATER, TOMATOE)
1   (MILK, EGG)
2   (CHOPSTICKS)
```

`df['NUM_ITEMS'] = df.ITEMS.len()`: does not work

`df['NUM_ITEMS'] = df.ITEMS.count()`: adds a column with the total number of rows in the DataFrame

I use `df['NUM_ITEMS'] = df.ITEMS.astype(str).str.count('\', \'') + 1`, but I guess it's not the best way. I'm sure there is a direct way to do it, but I can't see it.

Final DataSet:

```
           ITEMS            NUM_ITEMS
0   (EGG, WATER, TOMATOE)      3
1   (MILK, EGG)                2
2   (CHOPSTICKS)               1
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) and pass func `len`:

```
In [392]:
df['NUM_ITEMS'] = df['ITEMS'].apply(len)
df

Out[392]:
                   ITEMS  NUM_ITEMS
0  (EGG, WATER, TOMATOE)          3
1            (MILK, EGG)          2
2          (CHOPSTICKS)           1
```